# 18.04 downgrade from bionic-proposed to main

Tags: gnome, 18.04, freeze

My Ubuntu 18.04 installation sometimes randomly freezes. I saw in one question that maybe this is a Gnome problem, and the solution proposed was to downgrade from bionic-proposed to main.
What does that mean, and how can I do that?